# Start graph from nth index in Pchart

Tags: php, mysql, pchart

I am using PChart library, and I wanted to start graph from 5th index on x-axis. Is there any idea? I am already doing this:

```
$myData->AddPoints(array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"), "xlabel");
```

I am getting my data in array `$x`, this is the data to be plotted:

```
$myData->addPoints($x, "pvalues");
```

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:mysql]?

Comment: good it worked, Thanks,
that worked but
$myData->addPoints((VOID, VOID, VOID, VOID, $x), "pvalues");

it is not working, I want to add VOID to my array values.

Comment: If you want to reply to my comment, include `@Palec` somewhere in your reply, preferably at the beginning. See [How do comment @replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/238706) on Meta. This notifies me that I got a reply. I already replied to your comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `VOID` to reserve the space for points not in the graph. See the [basic syntax tutorial](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.basic.syntax.html).

Comment: good it worked, Thanks,
that worked but
$myData->addPoints((VOID, VOID, VOID, VOID, $x), "pvalues");

it is not working, I want to add VOID to my array values.

Comment: @SKP You mean `$myData->addPoints(array(VOID, VOID, VOID, VOID, $x), "pvalues");`. The [`addPoints` manual page](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.dataset.addpoints.html) says it should work, if I get it correctly. More info on that in [Missing points handling FAQ](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.missing.points.html).